# How to learn to handle HTTP requests of protected resources?

Tags: json, oauth, httprequest

I've wrote a [tiny script](http://joaoramos.org/labs/t+f) that retrieves publicly available data from some APIs, in JSON format. I'm now trying to get some protected data out from [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) (click stats from a given user) and so I obviously need to authenticate via OAuth.

I don't seem to understand the role of client id and secret, as well as the user API key. I also don't get how to grab an access token (maybe generated during OAuth authentication?) to authenticate my HTTP requests of protected data. Do you guys know any good (e)book, article or any other resources I should read to understand in detail these architectural nuances of authenticated data retrievals and HTTP requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly as you suspect. The access token is granted during the OAuth process, which is basically a three step rocket of getting

1. Temporary credentials for your application
2. An end user needs to authenticate those temporary credentials, which grants you a verifier token
3. And finally you exchange your temporary credentials and the user verification for an access token.

Depending on which language/framework you are using, there are often good libaries available to help you implement an OAuth client. Check out: http://oauth.net/code/

But you will be well served by a clear understanding of how the whole thing works. Twitter has a great tutorial about OAuth 1: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth.

Regarding OAuth 2. Check out http://hueniverse.com/2010/05/introducing-oauth-2-0/. Hueniverse is a good resource for all things OAuth by the way.